# CAShapeLayer position incorrect

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I'm having issues drawing a circle using `CAShapeLayer`. I have a custom view `MainLogoAnimationView` code as follows:

```
import UIKit

class MainLogoAnimationView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var customView: UIView!
    var redCircle: AnimationCircleView!


    // MARK: Object Lifecycle

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        _ = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MainLogoAnimationView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
        self.addSubview(customView)
        customView.frame = self.bounds
        let circleWidth = frame.size.width*0.25
        let yPos = frame.size.height/2 - circleWidth/2
        redCircle = AnimationCircleView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: yPos, width: circleWidth, height: circleWidth))
        redCircle.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        addSubview(redCircle)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

    }
}
```

In interface builder I created a light blue `UIView` and selected `MainLogoAnimationView` as the subview.

The `AnimationCircleView` is like so:

```
import UIKit

class AnimationCircleView: UIView {

    // MARK: Object lifecycle

    var circleColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor {
        didSet {
            shapeLayer.fillColor = circleColor
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    func setup() {
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: frame)
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = circleColor
        shapeLayer.frame = self.frame
        shapeLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Is seems the `CAShapeLayer` frame is incorrect and also the red circle is in the wrong position. It should be inside the yellow square. What am I doing wrong here? Any pointers would be really appreciated! Thanks!

UPDATE:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `AnimationCircleView` inside `setup` change

`shapeLayer.frame = self.frame`

**to**

`shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds`

This should ensure the gray colour is drawn inside the yellow rectangle.

**Edit:**

Similar to the answer above, changing

`let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: frame)`

**to**

`let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds)`

will solve your problem and draw circle inside the gray area.

`CAShapeLayer` frame is calculated relative to the position of the view it is added on, soo setting it equal to the frame, adds the `CAShapeLayer` at a x and y position offset from the origin by the value of the x and y passed in `self.frame`.

Comment: That moved the frame to the correct position but the circle is not centered inside. Image above^

Comment: Yeah i was about to ask that in me edit. `let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: frame)` , where are you getting the value of the frame from? If you debug it, you will see that the x and y position are again offset. It should be bounds here as well! Its the same issue as I answered mostly :)
Try changing it to bounds and it will work

Comment: That did it! Thanks!